# missing } inserted in my formula

Tags: equations

Latex has a missing } inserted error in my formula, I didnt see a missing thing in it :

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{3-5}
\begin{aligned}
u^{_{A}}_{i}$ - $u^{_{B}}_{i}$ = $\overline{\epsilon}_{ik}x^{_{A}}_{k} $ -$\overline{\epsilon}_{ik}x^{_{B}}_{k}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You mustn't have `$` inside `equation`. By the way, `aligned` does exactly nothing, here.

Comment: The code you posted has other errors. Why do you waste our time with code that clearly will not compile?

Comment: but I wrote the problem was solved !

Answer (score 5):

When `equation` starts, TeX is in math mode, so no `$` is necessary inside the environment; to be more precise, a `$` inside the environment will cause errors.

By the way, even in line you should not split formulas in that way; the input

```
$x$ - $y$
```

in normal text will produce a hyphen and not a minus sign, which is probably what you want.

Also `^{_{A}}` is wrong: the exponent is reduced in size, but positioned wrongly. If you *really* want a smaller exponent, the right way is

```
^{\scriptscriptstyle A}
```

but I strongly discourage you to do it.

You also have a useless `aligned` environment, that would only be useful for splitting the equation across lines. Note also that `\bar` is better than `\overline` in this case.

Correct input:

```
\begin{equation}\label{3-5}
u^{A}_{i} - u^{B}_{i} = \bar{\epsilon}_{ik}x^{A}_{k} -\bar{\epsilon}_{ik}x^{B}_{k}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

You may want to fine tune the positioning of subscripts by adding dummy superscripts to `\bar{\epsilon}`:

```
\begin{equation}\label{3-5}
u^{A}_{i} - u^{B}_{i} = \bar{\epsilon}^{}_{ik}x^{A}_{k} -\bar{\epsilon}^{}_{ik}x^{B}_{k}
\end{equation}
```

[image]